# how to pass these strings from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i have 4 strings in my application like this that i want to pass to my js file

```
$a1='[10,20,13,14]';
$a2='[17,15,14,16]';
$a3='[18,24,16,17]';
$a4='[15,54,18,27]';

echo $a1.",".$a2.",".$a3.",".$a4;
```

and my javascriptcode is

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           url: "loaddata.php",
               success: function(data)
            {
           alert(data); //alert 15,54,18,27


          }
     });
```

i can get just $a4 string, and i can not get other string

how can i pass these 4 strings in php and set these  4 variables in javascript

thanks;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encode them as JSON.

On the PHP side:

```
echo json_encode(array("a1" => $a1, "a2" => $a2, "a3" => $a3, "a4" => $a4));
```

On the JavaScript side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "loaddata.php",
    success: function(data) {
        var a1=data.a1;
        var a2=data.a2;
        var a3=data.a3;
        var a4=data.a4;
        // do something with a1, a2, a3 and a4
    }
});
```

And if you want `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, and `a4` to be arrays of numbers instead of strings containing numbers, just JSON decode the strings on the PHP side before sending them over:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "a1" => json_decode($a1),
    "a2" => json_decode($a2),
    "a3" => json_decode($a3),
    "a4" => json_decode($a4)
));
```

Comment: I don't think it's neccesary to nest the json_encode's. A wrapper json_encode jsonEncodes all the object, doesn't?

Comment: @Erik: Yes, but see, I'm not nesting `json_encode`s. It's decoding them, then re-encoding the complete structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use json_encode on the php side and pass the data back that way
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
return "{ A1: '[10,20,13,14]', A2: '[17,15,14,16]', A3: '[18,24,16,17]', A4: '[15,54,18,27]' }";
```

Though you could also just pass these as actual arrays by removing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the serialize() method. Pass the variables in a input field and:

```
$.post("loaddata.php", $("#ajaxform").serialize(), function(data){
  //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1='[10,20,13,14]';
$a2='[17,15,14,16]';
$a3='[18,24,16,17]';
$a4='[15,54,18,27]';

echo $a1.",".$a2.",".$a3.",".$a4;
```

will return

```
[10,20,13,14],[17,15,14,16],[18,24,16,17],[15,54,18,27]
```

this is not a valid JSON string.

You can return an object that contains an array of arrays like this:

```
echo "[".$a1.",".$a2.",".$a3.",".$a4."]";
// => [[10,20,13,14],[17,15,14,16],[18,24,16,17],[15,54,18,27]]
```

or you can do return an object with named keys to access the different arrays.

```
echo "{a1:".$a1.",a2:".$a2.",a3:".$a3",a4:".$a4."};
// => {a1:[10,20,13,14], a2:[17,15,14,16], a3:[18,24,16,17], a4:[15,54,18,27]}
```

---

Or even much butter: Don't build the JSON String on your own and use PHP's `json_encode` instead:

```
$a1=array(10,20,13,14);
$a2=array(17,15,14,16);
$a3=array(18,24,16,17);
$a4=array(15,54,18,27);

echo json_encode(array($a1,$a2,$a3,$a4));
// => [[10,20,13,14],[17,15,14,16],[18,24,16,17],[15,54,18,27]]
// or if you want an associative array
echo json_encode(array("a1" => $a1, "a2" => $a2, "a3"=> $a3, "a4" => $a4));
// => {a1:[10,20,13,14], a2:[17,15,14,16], a3:[18,24,16,17], a4:[15,54,18,27]}
```